# Connecting Newsletter Details to Header

Tags: adobe-indesign, cross-reference

I am new and learning InDesign, I am upgrading from Word and I was wondering if there was a way to link details within the newsletter to the header.

More specifically I have the issue number on the front page and I would like the headers (I made Master pages) to reflect the changed number on the front page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Text Variables](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-variables.html) can be used.

Type > Text Variables > Define.

Then name it, I used Issue Number to go with your question and whatever text you want.

[image]

Then just for example I created two text boxes and did Type > Variable > Insert > Issue Number

[image]

Now when I want to update I just edit that variable

[image]

Didn't screenshot but hit edit, changed it to Issue 02 and saved, which results in:

[image]